# issues in printing next() in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I'm having a weird issue with the command print(next()) in python 3.

When i use it to print on the console, it works perfectly, but when i try to save the output into a file, it doesn't work!
The commands that i'm using are the following:

```
for item in final:
    fasta = open(fname) # fname is the name if input file
    for line in fasta:
        line = line.strip()
        if item in line:
            item = item.strip()
            print('Line:', line, '\nNext line:', next(fasta)) # this works perfectly!
            print(line, next(fasta), file=open('finalList.fa', "a")) # this one doesn't work!
```

The output that I get from the last command's **next(fasta)** part is the **line+2** instead of **line+1**, like the one I get from the print on console command.

Does anyone has a clue about what is going on? Any tip will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, I just realized that that was the problem!! I never used next() command before! Thanks @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Calling `next` advances the given iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) (`fasta` in this case). Calling it multiple times will advance it multiple times and cause elements to be skipped. You need to save the return value in a variable if you want to use the data in different places:

```
if item in line:
    data = next(fasta) # Save it here
    item = item.strip()
    print('Line:', line, '\nNext line:', data) # Then use it multiple times here and below
    print(line, data, file=open('finalList.fa', "a"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the noob issue

Comment: @FernandaCosta No problem. We all made similar mistakes at one point.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to create a variable and pass the value of next(foo) in this variable, and finally print the variable ?

Comment: No problem, it' s sad that the others, just repeated my solution to gain reputation

Comment: You posted a fairly poorly explained answer that was phrased as a question. It would be disingenuous to say that I "just repeated" your solution when I gave much more detail and had already started writing my answer before you had posted yours.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that when you call **next()** command in python 3 it **reads correctly line+1 and when i call it again, it will consider line the next(line) instead of line, so it prints next(next(line) which is line+2!**

So i fixed it with just removing the print in the console command line.

Thank you all and sorry about the noob problem!